# Why yields in cartesian product in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table a    Table b   result
id name    id name   id name
1  a1      1  b1     1  b1
2  a2      2  b2     2  b2
3  a3                1  b1
4  a4                2  b2
                     1  b1
                     2  b2
                     1  b1
                     2  b2
```

I have two tables a and b,when I conduct such query

> SELECT b.* FROM a As a,b AS b

,it has the cartesian product but I do not understand,this statement select data from table b only but why

> a AS a

changed the final result?IMO table a has nothing to do with the result and it is meanningless

Comment: Because you're selecting from two tables. What other result would you expect?

Comment: because you are creating a join between the two tables. THe rows in table B are each duplicated for each valid row in table A, which in your case is all rows from table A, because you did not specify a condition. Read joins documentation

Answer (score 2):

When you don't specify *any* columns from table `a`, this is the expected behavior...

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a As a,b AS b
```

Or simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM a,b
```

Is what you probably want if you seek a Cartesian product.

**EDIT**
`It defaults to select all columns from table a if I don't write a.*?It is by default?`

**No.** You used `SELECT b.* FROM`, which means:  give me all columns that are coming from table `b`. `SELECT a.*, b.*` means give me all columns that are coming from table `a` and `b`. `SELECT * FROM` means give me all columns, no matter where they come from...

Comment: It defaults to select all columns from table a if I don't write a.*?It is by default?

Comment: If I don't specify any columns from table a like SELECT b.* FROM a AS a,b AS b,it causes the value from table b duplicated according to table a,but all the data are coming from table b,I'm wondering why table a causes duplicated data when no data comming from a?

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not specify the column that links the two tables. What do you expect to get? If you don't want to have a cartesian result build a query similar to this,

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM a As a, b AS b
WHERE a.columnname = b.columnName
```

Answer (score 2):

Using aliases has no effect. That is, these two queries are identical:

```
SELECT b.* FROM a AS a, b AS b
SELECT b.* FROM a, b
```

Now that is out of the way, the query is behaving as expected: Rows of b are output once for every row of a - ie you have coded a cartesian product.

There is nothing mysterious about your query.

Answer (score 2):

The `select` clause does not filter rows. It's merely a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29) of the values. The rows are filtered in the `where` clause, or alternatively, in the `on` part of a `join` clause.

What you have said is:

1. Get every row of table a and every row of table b (`from` clause, produces a cartesian set)
2. (nonexistant) Filter those rows according to a predicate (`where` or `on` clause)
3. Out of those result rows, display only the fields that come from the b table. (`select` clause)